Is it possible to send an email to validate it when the user is created by an admin in AWS Cognito?
I'm using CDK for the infrastructure and Amplify for the front end. I'm new to it. So maybe I was missing something.
What I want is to send an email with a verification code to validate it when a user is created by the command AdminCreateUserCommand and not the default invitation email. I use Amplify in the front end to handle the sign-in.
I implemented the configuration in the cognito constructor to verify the user's email but it didn't work.
I read the documentation to see how could I implement this feature, but I didn't find anything about it. Some posts and blogs said that it's not possible to do this thing using admin flow, I mean creating a user by  AdminCreateUserCommand. Only in normal flow, I mean when the user signs up themselves. Also, I added a trigger lambda to customize the message.
Note: the conditions work as expected.
The constructor cognito:
autoVerify: {
                email: props.emailVerificationRequired
            },
            userVerification: props.userVerificationRequired
                ? {
                      emailSubject: 'Verify your email for our awesome app!',
                      emailBody:
                          'Hello {username}, Thanks for signing up to our awesome app! Your verification code is {####}',
                      emailStyle: cognito.VerificationEmailStyle.CODE
                  }
                : undefined,
            standardAttributes: {
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    mutable: false
                }
            },
            customAttributes: {
                locale: new cognito.StringAttribute({ mutable: true })
            },
            lambdaTriggers: {
                preSignUp: preSignUpLambda,
                customMessage: props.userVerificationRequired ? customMessage : undefined
            },

Lambda in charge of creating a user:
const userPoolId = process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID;
    console.log('userPoolId', userPoolId);
    const params = {
        UserPoolId: userPoolId,
        Username: validatedEmail,
        DesiredDeliveryMediums: ['EMAIL' as const],
        TemporaryPassword: validatedPassword,
        UserAttributes: [
            {
                Name: 'locale',
                Value: validatedLocale
            },
            {
                Name: 'email',
                Value: validatedEmail
            }
        ],
        ClientMetadata: {
            appName: process.env.APP_NAME || 'myApp'
        }
    };
    console.log('params', params);
    try {
        await cognitoClient.send(new AdminCreateUserCommand(params));

